# Example for std.lines(arr) function of Jsonnet

Tags: github, ubuntu-16.04, jsonnet

Can anyone help me with an example for std.lines(arr) function of Jsonnet? 
I am trying to create a bash script to clone multiple git repositories using values from an array. My array structure is given below.

`gitRepo : [
                {
                   github_repo: "github.com/abcd.git",
                   github_id: "tom",
                   github_access_token: "1aae0a6dc19aef327565"
                },
                {
                   github_repo: "github.com/qwerty.git",
                   github_id: "alice",
                   github_access_token: "2e2eef327565"
                },
              ],
}`

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution for this from jsonnet google groups.

```
local config = [
  {
    github_repo: 'github.com/abcd.git',
    github_id: 'tom',
    github_access_token: '1aae0a6dc19aef327565',
  },
  {
    github_repo: 'github.com/qwerty.git',
    github_id: 'alice',
    github_access_token: '2e2eef327565',
  },
];
std.lines([
  'git clone %(github_repo)s --user=%(github_id)s --token=%(github_access_token)s' % item
  for item in config
])
```

test it with `jsonnet -S test.jsonnet`. (Note the Capital `-S` flag)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jsonnet/array%7Csort:date/jsonnet/SGADdQQ-vBs/Tig8DnsRBQAJ

Comment: Testing only works with `jsonnet -S test.jsonnet`.  Note the capital `-S`.